# Azure WebJobs - Find invocation/s by parameter value

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Is it possible to search for invocations by function name and value in Azure? I have been fiddling about in the interface and I can get to a list of ALL invocations by function name here:

https://{WebApplicationName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions

but this list can contain many thousands of invocations for any given function so it would take an age to page through looking for the one particular invocation I need.

I'd like to be able to search through these invocations based on the parameters that were passed to the function. This would narrow the results sufficiently to enable me to see the particular invocation details I need.

Is this possible? I've tried googling and fumbling through the interface but couldnt find anything of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't a general function search capability currently. If you know the function invocation ID (e.g. if it was written to your error log, or you logged it yourself for correlation), you can go directly to a single function invocation via `https://{site}.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions/invocations/{invocation_id}`, but no general search by string.

We do have a [backlog item](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/96) in our public repo for adding function search capabilities. You might consider adding your request there for tracking.